# CF - Working with Apps and changing env variables

Tags: devops, manifest, cloud-foundry

I'm new on this technology (studying for now) and I have a doubt on how to properly work with the Apps.

For example, I have an **app-gateway** with 2 instances (Traefik), and in there I'm using env variables like **RESTRICTED_NETWORK_01** and **RESTRICTED_NETWORK_02**.

I want to replace de IP value of RESTRICTED_NETWORK_02 and apply the change without any impact to the gateway/redirect users service.

Should I just use the command:

```
cf set-env app-gateway RESTRICTED_NETWORK_02 [ipvalue]/24
```

then

```
cf restart-app-instance app-gateway 0
wait until the instance restarts and apply
cf restart-app-instance app-gateway 1
```

Is it the right steps I should follow for this situation?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

> cf restart-app-instance app-gateway 0

This will probably not do what you want, at least not reliably. This command works by terminating your application instance, which then allows it to be restarted. It's typically useful if you have an app instance that's in a bad state but hasn't crashed or failed health checks (or for demos where you need to make an app crash).

In terms of env variables, it doesn't work so well. This is because the env variable changes you've made reside in Cloud Controller, but your application runs on the scheduler (Diego). The scheduler has a copy of data from the Cloud Controller that tells it how to run the app, including environment variables that should be set. The command you're referencing doesn't result in Cloud Controller updating the application definition that it has sent to the scheduler (Diego). It simply results in the process being terminated and restarted by the scheduler using the same definition.

Your mileage may vary on this one, as I've heard some reports of people saying that `cf restart-app-instance` works for updating env variables (I don't really see how it would, but I haven't investigated their claims either). You could try it and see, but the stories I've seen have typically ended with problems. tl-dr it doesn't consistently work.

To reliably update env variables, you need to use `cf restart`. This will restart all application instances.

What you should do to restart app instances without downtime is to use the `cf restart --strategy=rolling` option (available in version 7 of the cf cli). This will roll out the changes and so long as you have multiple application instances, should not result in downtime.

Comment: Thank you very much! A lot of valuable information about CF I didn't know.
I need to update my cf version (v6.42) to v7. 
I did a test with cf v3-zdt-restart but my app was in a eternal deploy, I had to use cf v3-cancel-zdt-push to stop it.
The strange part is that I even "lost" one instance in the process. The app-gateway was reduced to 1/1 against the previous 2/2 (even restart couldn't brind the second instance back).
Really appreciate the help Daniel!

Comment: You may also want to talk with your platform operator and see what version of CF they have deployed. Pretty much all recent versions should have good support for rolling deploy, but if you're seeing issues with it and you're on an older version then your operations team may need to upgrade. While having cf7 is important, it's also important to have a recent version of Cloud Controller and other backend services.

Comment: I can understand. The worst part is that they are using the same version (v6.42 from 2019), really outdated unfortunately. I'll check with the main team if they have some plan to upgrade CF, Cloud Controller and backend services.
Thanks again, since I'm new those informations are really important to me.